Activity not recreated when receiving data from send intent
I was following this article to make a compose app a share target, but it wasn't working.
After adding an intent filter to the manifest, the app can be opened via the share menu.
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="_">
<!--            android:launchMode="singleInstance"-->
<!--            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"-->
<!--            >-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

(not sure about launch mode)
However, it seems that the activity isn't re-created, so I am not able to print the intent with its data.
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.d("IMPORT 2", "$intent")
        setContent {
            
        }
    }
}

Also, it isn't the correct composable that is shown. It only works if I close the app first so that the send intent opens the app for the first time.
@Composable
fun Navigation(appState: PoiAppState, paddingValues: PaddingValues) {
    NavHost(appState.navController, startDestination = Screen.Home.route, Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
        ... 
        composable(
            route = "share_target_route"
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    mimeType = "text/*"
                },
                navDeepLink {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    mimeType = "image/*"
                }
            )
        ) {
            ShareTargetScreen()
        }     
       ...
    }
}


Override onNewIntent() in your activity to collect any Intent objects delivered to your activity after it was created.

@CommonsWare Thank you, onNewIntent does work. Now the problem is that the ShareTargetScreen isn't shown. (are we supposed to setContent inside onNewIntent)

Override onNewIntent() and, from there, call handleDeepLink() on your NavController.
